# AS3 class / static variable init timing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I have a pure AS3 project (no mxml).

When compile using flex SDK 4.6, a class (and its static variables) is inited at the very first time when it is referenced (when static member being used or class instance being created).

When compile using air SDK 24.0, many class (and its static variables) are inited right at application start, not right before they are referenced. Why? Is there any compile option or SWF meta tag to prevent this?

My static variables need some other data to init, those data are dynamic loaded at run time, not immediately available at application start. So, i do not want them to be inited so early.

Comment: use a singleton with private instance member variables and public static getter/setters http://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2006/07/as3_singletons.html

Comment: @autum The Flex SDK uses ASC 1.0 while the AIR SDK uses ASC 2.0, this results in different behavior, such as the one you described. I agree on using the above approach.

Comment: self-implemented "late init" would be acceptable for big singletons, but not a good approach when you have hundreds of run time constants in hundreds of classes. it makes code verbose and ineffective. I insist compiler should do that job. And it is not mentioned here: https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-builder/actionscript-compiler-backward-compatibility.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My static variables need some other data to init, those data are
>   dynamic loaded at run time, not immediately available at application
>   start. So, i do not want them to be inited so early.

Doing this is dangerous to begin with, even if it worked in ASC 1.0. If you need to load data before computing some derived values, you shouldn't rely on static initialization.

You could use a singleton, or just use a static `initialize()` method which you explicitly call after the data is loaded:

```
private function handleDataLoaded(e:DataEvent):void {
    MyStaticStuff.initialize(e.data);
}
```

Or, as a drop-in replacement, you can refactor your static variables to getters which internally call an init function:

```
public class MyStaticStuff {
    // before
    public static const SOME_VALUE:Number = LoadedData.data.something;

    // after
    private var initialized:Boolean = false;

    private static _SOME_VALUE:Number;

    public static function get SOME_VALUE():Number {
        initialize();
        return _SOME_VALUE:Number;
    }

    private static function initialize():void {
        if (!initialized) {
            initialized = true;
            _SOME_VALUE = LoadedData.data.something;
        }
    }
}
```

In this case places that use `MyStaticStuff.SOME_VALUE` don't have to be changed, and the values will be initialized the first time they are *referenced* like you had before. But it would probably be a better pattern to refactor your code to use a singleton and/or explicit initialization.

Comment: "static variable be inited at the very first time when its class is referenced" is a must in many programming languages, like Java, C++. With that, code   can be simple and effective: "public static var a:A = initA();". Just one single line. And, any reference to "a" is just a variable reference. However, when using "late init", code is verbose, ineffective.  all references to "a" become method calls, that would be OK, if it is just a big singleton, but bad for constants (i mean run time, not compile time). So it is better if there is some option in compiler.

Comment: Yes but it's hard to effectively reason *when* a class is "first referenced". You are writing fragile code, even if it works. Explicitness is always better when you know you have dependency timing (asynchronous loading of data in your case) to account for. Your broken project is case in point. You might be able to shuffle things to get it to behave differently in ASC 2, but I cannot suggest that as a good idea.

Comment: I know the dependency, and i can control it, just load depended resources when application start, and after load complete, init all other classes. Oh! I found a solution: compile all other classes as a module, then embed the module swf in main swf. In main swf, load resource first, after load complete, load module swf, so module classes never get chance to be init before depended resources. Yet not a good solution either.